# is there prettier syntax for a c++ iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, design-patterns, syntactic-sugar

Is there a prettier / less-verbose way to use iterators in C++? From the tutorials I've seen, I either set up typedefs everywhere (which gets tedious to do for a lot of one-off for-loops):

```
typedef std::vector<std:pair<int, int> >::iterator BlahIterator;
```

or have verbose-looking for loops like:

```
for (std::vector<std:pair<int, int> >::iterator it = ... ) ...
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, use C++11 and say `auto`!

Comment: It also helps to use STL algorithms when you can to avoid the loop syntax altogether.

Comment: Another idea is to `typedef` your container. That makes such iterator declarations less ugly and more maintainable.  http://drdobbs.com/184401853

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [boost](http://www.boost.org), you can use the [FOR_EACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/foreach.html) macro.

```
typedef pair<int, int> tElem;
BOOST_FOREACH( tElem e, aVector )
{
    cout << e.first << " " << e.second << '\n';
}
```

Comment: it's even *prettier* with C++11 `BOOST_FOREACH( const auto& i, aVector )`

Comment: it's even *more prettier* with pure C++11: `for(const auto& i : aVector) {}`

Comment: @In silico, it should have been an answer (see how many upvotes you have got already).

Answer (score 8):

In C++11 you can use the range-based for loop combined with the auto keyword:

```
for (auto& it : v) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The algorithms sort of get around that particular problem.
Especially with the new lambda functions.

```
std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), Action()); /* Where Action is your functor */
```

Or with lambda:

```
std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [](type const& e) { /* Stuff */ });
```

Note: don't fall into the trap of using std::for_each to replace all loops. There are a whole bunch of algorithms that use iterators that allow you to manipulate or do operations based on the contents of a container.

Comment: The form `std::for_each(x.begin(), x.end(), ...)` seems so common I am surprised there isn't a much easier to type/read shorthand for it...

Comment: @NetMage: There is now. the range based for statement is the new way to do it.

Comment: To me that feels like a `for` statement, and not a improvement/replacement on functional programming style. C# with LINQ has both.

Comment: @NetMage The C++ language does not place any limitations on the implementation. So `for(;;)` and `for(:)` and `std::for_each()` can be optimized underneath the covers as required. As for `functional programming style` not sure how that is relevant especially as C++ is multi-paradigm.

Comment: How do you use for(:) in a chain?

Comment: @NetMage Why would you want to! Note:  multi-paradigm means you can use the most appropriate style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160037/discussion-between-netmage-and-loki-astari).

Answer (score 2):

With c++0x you can use the auto keyword:

```
for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {}
```

Comment: Just curious: the `.begin()` method can return both `iterator` and `const_iterator`. How, using the c++0x syntax, can I tell the compiler that I want `const_iterator`?

Comment: @Michał: Use `.cbegin()` and `.cend()` to specify `const_iterators`

Comment: @Michal: this depends on the const-ness of `v`. If `v` is not `const`, then the non-const overload is selected. As Blastfurnace said, C++0x introduce a new pair `cbegin` / `cend` to allow getting `const_iterator` from a non-const container without hacking.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the following naming pattern:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Blah;
typedef std::vector<Blah> Blahs;
```

and then use `Blahs::iterator`, i.e I don't name the iterator but the container (and usually the thing contained in it).
`typedef` is a very useful abstraction mechanism.

Note that a vector of "Blah" is called "Blahs" (i.e. just the plural), not a "BlahVector", because the specific container doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to write your loop (or whatever code that uses the iterator) into a small generic algorithm of its own. By making it a template, the compiler can/will deduce the iterator type automatically:

```
template <class T>
do_something(T begin, T end) { 
    for (T pos = begin; pos != end; ++pos) 
        do_something_with(*pos);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I usually define this, though I've been told I'm going to hell for it:

```
#define forsn(i, s, n) for(int i = (s); i < (n); ++i)
#define forn(i, n) forsn(i, 0, n)
#define forall(it, g) for(typeof g.begin() it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it)
```

Then, to loop from 0 to n, a common task, I say `forn(i, n) foo(i);`, and to loop any standard container c, I say `forall(it, c) foo(it);` Do note that `typeof` is a GCC extension to the standard.

Comment: Of course you are! You rely on macros + compiler extensions when you could use templated functions + predicates :)